# I subscribed to an RSS feed in Thunderbird. How do I find the link for the feed that I used to subscribe from within Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, rss

When I subscribe to an RSS feed in Thunderbird 24.6 (on Windows 7), I find the link to the RSS feed I want, click Subscribe, and add the link. Now, I don't remember where I found the link, but I'm still subscribed to the RSS feed in Thunderbird. How do I find/copy this link so I can send it to someone else, subscribe to it in different software, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Thunderbird, select the root folder of your RSS subscriptions, titled "News Account", and click "Manage Subscriptions" in the pane on the right:

[image: root folder, pane on right]

In the window that comes up (shown below), click the arrow next to the feed title to expand the feed; the "Feed URL" is what you're after.

[image: manage subscriptions window]